# Cucumber "No route matches [GET]" error on POST form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm running a simple test which submits a form via POST which works when tested manually but my test is failing with the error

```
No route matches [GET] "/doconfirm"  (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

The route is defined in my routes file as post-only

```
post '/doconfirm' => 'application#do_confirm', :as => :do_confirm
```

When I look at the html output from the test it contains a post form:

```
<form action="/doconfirm" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <div class="email-field input-field">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
        <label for="email">email</label>
    </div>
    <button name="button" type="submit" value="register">register</button>
</form>
```

I'm running Rails 4.2.0, Cucumber 1.3.20, Cucumber Rails 1.4.2, Capybara 2.4.4 using the poltergeist driver.

Why is my test trying to submit my form via GET and not POST? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I see a spare `</span>` in there right after the button.  What does the view look like?

Comment: This was a simplification of the output that I cleaned up, it's actually compiled HAML so there's not much chance of any HTML errors.

Comment: Can you post the test that you're running when this occurs?

Comment: @jljohnstone, thanks for your help. I just tried reducing the code to remove anything that might complicate finding the culprit and it started working again, even when I put the original code back in place. I guess I'll have to put this one down to some sort of caching issue unless it sneaks back in again tomorrow.